# CORS with php session

Tags: php, http-headers, cors, session-cookies

I am working with CORS on a website.

Code sample:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
```

This code is working fine, but it's returning a new session id every time.

**How can I maintain the session data in this situation?**

Answer (score 6):

Although you allow access from external domains with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the session itself is cookie based.

If the script which makes the request is delivered from the external domain, it will not be able to read the cookie and pass it to your server.

Solution: Deliver the JS which makes the call from the same context (i.e. same protocol/domain/port) as the AJAX service. Also make sure that the cookie itself is not restricted to a different subdomain or path.

DO NOT try passing the session identifier by POST or GET requests, this will make your application vulnerable to CSRF.

By the way, setting the allowed origin to `*` is also discouraged, because it can also be used for XSS/CSRF, in combination with other techniques. Please do limit requests to the third-party domain.

Last, but not least, you might also want to look into the subject of preflight requests via HTTP OPTIONS.

Comment: Is there no way to tell client and server that they are allowed to work together, but setting them on the same domain?

Comment: @helle They can work together, but they can’t share a cookie. Cookies are always bound to a domain. However, you could e.g. use a token and send it as a header in order to emulate a cookie. But be careful not to run into security issues such as XSS or CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

A server (in this case the `PHP` application) can have a session with many different clients at the same time. There is no way for the session to tell which session belongs to which client without having the `PHPSESSID` cookie. This cooke has to set in the request header for `PHP` to identify the client.